# The sound of Flutter app is paused when taking the airpods out of the ear on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am making an application that uses the "Assets audio player" library to play background music for the application. The problem I have is that the sound of the application is affected by the wireless headset. If I take out a headset (left or right) the app's sound is paused, and when I put the headset in my ear, the sound won't continue.

Is there a way I can disable this or is there a way to prevent headphones from affecting the app's sound?
Please give me the solution.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you register a "Pause" call in your app? The default behavior for AirPods is to pause the current playback item when one bud is removed. IIRC, when the bud is re-inserted, a "Play" call should be sent. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter for more info.

Comment: I don't register the "Pause" call in the app. I just play a background music and repeat it like below code.
       assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio(_backgroundMusicPath),
         loopMode: LoopMode.single,
       );
I went through your link, but I only work with Dart and have never used Swift. Looks like I have to tamper with the IOS related source code in the library.
Can you help me make it more clear?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't worked with this Flutter library. `assets_audio_player` seems to interface with iOS APIs here: https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer/blob/master/darwin/Classes/Music.swift
However, keep in mind that for 99% of users, the expected behavior for any playback app is to stop it when an earbud is removed. The sole exception that comes to mind are voice calls, where pausing/resuming doesn't make sense. Does it make sense for your app to go against this behavior? Does the playback resume when the user starts playback again?

Comment: I edited the source code based on your instructions, now my app works fine.
Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad you could find a solution to this issue - you figured that one out yourself, though! ;) If you have the time, can you maybe add a summary to your original posting so that future visitors can better understand what to do here?